# Запись значения из QSpinBox в переменную int

Tags: c++, qt5

Пытаюсь записать значение из QSpinBox в переменную int с помощью слота:

```
void SpinBoxer::slotSpin(int num) {
    this->num = num;
}
```

далее `connect`:

```
QObject::connect(spin, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SLOT(slotSpin(int)));
```

Где `spin` это `QSpinBox`

Выдает такую ошибку `QObject::connect: No such slot QGroupBox::slotSpin(int)`

Comment: Попробуйте так: `QObject::connect(spin, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(slotSpin(int)));`

Comment: Все тот же `QObject::connect: No such slot QGroupBox::slotSpin(int)`

Comment: метод `slotSpin` объявлен как слот? и в каком классе он объявлен?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver да конечно:
`public slots:
    void slotSpin(int value);`

Comment: где пишете `connect`? приведите более полный код, так не понятно, где именно ошибка

Comment: `SpinBoxer::SpinBoxer(QGroupBox *grb) : QGroupBox("Колличество символов", grb)
{
    starterSpin();
    QObject::connect(spin, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(slotSpin(int)));
}`

Comment: попробуйте синтаксис: `connect(ptr1, &Class1::signalFunc, ptr2, &Class2::slotFunc);`
(доступно в qt5)

Comment: @asianirish, каким способом мне вставить значение в сигнал? `slotSpin(int)`

Comment: `enum valueChanged(xxx);` (или же сигнал будет вызываться самим спином), приконекченный слот получит значение xxx в своем аргументе

Comment: @asianirish, Попробуйте написать как ответ.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте синтаксис для коннекта:

```
connect(spin, &QSpinBox::valueChanged, this, &SpinBoxer::slotSpin);
```

https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax